# Is it possible to take 2 separate videos and put them side by side in AWS elastic transcoder

Tags: aws-elastictranscoder

I want to create an app where band members can collaborate and record individual performances and then I would like to put them all in one video automatically. I'll have to figure out how to sync them up bit assuming that is solved, can AWS elastic transcoder combine videos to play side by side or multiple videos combined into one screen (like a tic tac toe board)?